# Visual Studio 16.8.1 Always Showing One of The Processes Crashed (Code Editor/CodeAnalysis Crash)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, issue-tracking

Sometimes CodeAnalysis Crashes When I Write Code, and Visual Studio Tells Me To Save Files, Close And Reopen Visual Studio. It Fixes When I Open And Close It But It Crashes Again For A Time.

Version: 16.8.1

Info:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: Operation canceled.
    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException ()
    at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.EndWaitForConnection (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
    at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteEndPoint.InvokeAsync [T] (<Unknown Parameters>)
```

Is There a Temporary Solution to the Problem?

Comment: I am Not Use Anti-Malware or Anti-Virus Product

Comment: Disabled Windows Defender and Uninstalled Third Party Programs

Comment: Updated to 16.8.1 and issue started

Comment: Since 16.8.2 has been released, please try to update vs to latest version. If the issue still starts, we suggest you report it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in 16.8.2 update.

Use Installer to update to 16.8.2

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you can mark this as an answer.