# Getting exception error every few minutes in visual studio forcing me to shut down and re open the visual studio, Any work around to fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2019 community version 16.8.1 after did a clean format and install my windows 10.
Then it all started it was not before. Maybe it's something with my networking ? but I didn't find any solution/s.

The message in the visual studio is show in the top of the visual studio in yellow. Then the intellisense is not working and I need to shut down the visual studio and re open it but it's happening too much times.

The exception is :

```
System.OperationCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.EndWaitForConnection(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar,Func`2 endFunction,Action`1 endAction,Task`1 promise,Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteEndPoint.InvokeAsync[T](<Unknown Parameters>)
```

Comment: i think the msdn forum might be a better place for this kind of question - and if it's a bug in vs itself, a good way to let the developers know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is to use version 16.8.2 as it was mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64942712/1362723) on the same question.

Comment: I can't be sure 100% but I already updated the visual studio before you answered and so far it's fine. I will keep watching the visual studio and will report if the problem will be back. Thanks.